# jQuery Plugin Suggestion For Asp.net Search

Tags: jquery, asp.net, search, webforms, full-text-search

I have a web page based on Asp.net Web Forms. I want to use a plugin for better search experience. I want to use a cached dataset for search. jQuery chosen, select plugins not good for a textbox. Autocomplete plugins searching live and didn't work for 2 words. For example I user write word autocomplete doesn't find "Hello World".

What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found good qquery plugin for search an http://easyautocomplete.com